# wget: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: wget

I want to download an entire website that is protected by NTLM but it fails with:

```
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, warte auf Antwort... 401 Unauthorized

Unbekanntes Authentifizierungsschema.

Authorisierung fehlgeschlagen.
```

This is the command I used:

```
# wget --http-user=expample.com/username --http-password='mypassword' http://example.com/ -v
```

The login credentials are 100% correct.

```
# wget --version
GNU Wget 1.13.4 übersetzt unter linux-gnu.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls -ntlm +opie +ssl/gnutls

Wgetrc:
    /root/.wgetrc (Benutzer)
    /etc/wgetrc (System)
Lokale: /usr/share/locale
Übersetzt: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc"
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -I../lib
    -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Iyes/include -g -O2 -fstack-protector
    --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security
    -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall
Gebunden: gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat
    -Werror=format-security -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall
    -Wl,-z,relro -Lyes/lib -lgnutls -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lz -lidn -lrt
    ftp-opie.o gnutls.o ../lib/libgnu.a
```

Comment: Have you tried starting a session with your browser and using the cookies of your logged in session with wget?

Comment: I think there is no session to save because it's a plain auth:
http://0x05.de/iis.JPG

Comment: I would use something like the "live HTTP headers" add on (for Firefox) to trace the whole communication from the web browser and then mimmic that communication with wget.

Answer (score 1):

The `--http-user` and `--http-passwd` are only useful in conjunction with [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on the website.

This is rarely used and easily recognised as the username and password are prompted outside of the web pages asking for a username and password, and prompting the server says: .

The site most likely uses some other scheme to query username and password and keep that for the sessions (usually some cookie based scheme). `wget` can handle that as well (look at the man page and search for `--save-session-cookie` and `load-cookies`), but you might be better of automating this with something like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), where you tell a real browser to do the work, and where you programmatically fill in the fields and click buttons. In my experience that always works, even with heavily javascript infused websites.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply.
It's a basic plain auth: http://0x05.de/iis.JPG
But it's an IIS webserver with an Active Directory and the user to login is a domain user.

Comment: And with a normal webbrowser you can login? With javascript turned off for that site?

Comment: yes that works fine.